# Highlight cells with exact dublicate value/text

Tags: excel, duplicates

I currently use a rule to highlight cells that got duplicate value.
The problem is that it counts cells that start with "0" as a duplicate with on with the same number except the "0".

For example. One cell with the text 01234 counts as a duplicate with the text 1234 but it shouldn't because they are 2 different things.

So I Wonder if there's a "custom rule" that can go for the exact number.
It's at work and vba is blocked So cant do a macro for it, so need it to be a rule.

Comment: "One cell with the text 01234 counts as a duplicate with the text 1234 but it should because they are 2 different things" So should be or shouldn't be ?

Comment: Shouldnt, updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I think that Excel convert the text into numeric. You can solve this problem by prefixing all the numbers with an underscore, wich forces them into text. You can use this formula :

```
="_"&A1
```

*In my example the data starts in A1. Then you fill down this formula to the entire colomn.*

Now, the Conditional formatting will work with duplicates in the column with the formula. If you want to remove the formula, you can Copy/Paste the entire column with the PasteSpecial --> Values

Comment: The issue is that the workbook the "text" needs to be in a specific column. And there are no extra column to add any code to get & modify the value. Or my first solution would have been the same as u, but instead of "_" i would have used "'"&cell. Because the ' make the value in the cell into text.

Comment: So I need a rule that use exact duplicate text. But I cant figure out a code that would work for it right now